# PHP FPM Status via PHP

Tags: php

Is there a way to get the infos from the PHP-FPM Status page directly via PHP? I don't want to view it on a seperate page. Also I won't do some Shell call for it. Best practise would be calling a function in PHP and get an array with all the stats.

I'm talking about this stats: https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/php/fpm-status-page/

Comment: Please don't include rude words when posting, they have no place here

Comment: It seems the page you mention clearly describes the way to get what you want

Comment: Yes, it describes how you get it on a seperate page. But I want to get it in PHP to do some stuff with it.

Answer (score 0):

Just load it from server in your PHP script... for example your script my_status.php can do `<?php echo file_get_contents("http://www.server.com/fpm-status"); ?>` and either output it directly with some other page contents, or do any manipulation on it.